# Riddle: Who wrote this doctoral thesis?

Tags: riddle

Who wrote this doctoral thesis?

> *Published:* August 1960
>
> *Abstract:* Subject responses are investigated to antemeridial comestibles in the 510 nm range. Verbal responses was elicited by a hobbit companion on a sample of size n=1. Aversive reactions were reproduced for a wide variety of environmental scenarios, including: cuboid containment, vulpine proximity, domestic setting, liquid precipitation, and locomotive transport. However, the results are contraindicated by a singular yet strongly outlying data point at the end of testing.

---

In case it's not clear, this is a riddle in a fanciful frame. This is not an actual doctoral thesis.

Comment: This sounds like a question from You Don't Know Jack

Comment: I just stumbled across this, and it's hilarious.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is an abstract to

> *Green Eggs and Ham*, a children's book by Dr. Seuss (Theodor Geisel), published in 1960.
>  "Antemeridial comestibles" are morning foods (eggs and ham), and light with wavelength 510 nm is green light.
>  "Hobbit companion" refers to Sam, who was the companion of Frodo in *The Lord of the Rings*, as well as the character Sam (Sam-I-Am) in Seuss' book who offers green eggs and ham to another character.
>  The aversive responses are the other character's rejections of green eggs and ham in a variety of locations and situations: "cuboid containment" (*I do not like them in a box*), "vulpine proximity" (*I do not like them with a fox*), "liquid precipitation" (*I will not eat them in the rain*), and "locomotive transport" (*I will not eat them on a train*). 
> The refusals are always addressed to Sam by name (*I do not like them, Sam-I-Am*).
>  The results are contraindicated because at the end of the story, the character tries green eggs and ham, likes them, and recants the earlier statements.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that Sam is the *offerer*, not the one being offered these items. This points to a slight problem with either the puzzle or answer.

Comment: I am a little confused. Is Sam-I-Am the offerer's name, or is the narrator stating that he is Sam?

Comment: I guess it's pretty clear Sam is the offerer, so I agree this is problematic.

Comment: The offerer. I don't believe the other is ever named. (source: 150 bazillion readings).

Comment: Oh, I had interpreted Sam as being the refuser, saying Sam-I-am to remind us who he is, and alternating conversation with an offerer.

Comment: Well, Wikipedia agrees that Sam is the offerer, so looks like I've misunderstood it since childhood. I'll edit the riddle.

Comment: "That Sam-I-Am, I do not like that Sam-I-Am"

Comment: This is spectacular, but wouldn't the literal answer to the question being asked, "*Who* wrote this doctoral thesis" is "Dr. Seuss"?